# let python know when I download from a specific web page

Tags: python

I want to write a python script that can detect when a pdf file is downloaded from a specific web page(s) and then automatically move that file from Downloads directory into another directory.

My problem (for the moment) is that I don't know how to monitor my downloads with python, in order for it to detect when a file is downloaded from a specific web address. I checked urllib/requests, but it doesn't seems to do what I need. Does anybody knows a module that I can use for this task?

Comment: try selenium, but python is not an appropriate solution for this, try to create a  browser add-ons use javascript  for this that is much appropriate solution

Comment: Depending on your OS you can maybe watch the download folder…

Comment: You might also consider installing or building some kind of browser extension which watches downloads. Browser extensions are surprisingly easy to write thanks to WebExtensions APIs.